What is the best way to create a dynamic menu system in MAUI?
I am new to MAUI. I am trying to create an app that upon user login retrieves all the menu items they have access to and creates a "button" for each, that when clicked either directs to that view, or if it's a sub-menu it directs to that menu and eventually links to the final views. I currently have a working demo by using a CollectionView that presents each item in the list inside a border to give it a button-look, but borders don't have a hover or click state, so I can't replicate the look of clicking a button. After digging into things, I'm questioning whether or not the CollectionView method is the right approach.
Here is my XAML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="GppScanMaui.Menu.MenuPage"
             x:Name="CurrentMenuPage">
    <CollectionView x:Name="MenuItemList"
                    BindingContext="{x:Reference CurrentMenuPage}"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemListData}"
                    ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged"
                    EmptyView="No access available">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="50, 10"
                        Padding="0, 10"
                        Stroke="#2B0B98"
                        StrokeThickness="4"
                        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="cpi_browser_logo.ico" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

                        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource White}, Light={StaticResource Black}, Default={StaticResource Black}}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontAttributes="Italic" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource White}, Light={StaticResource Black}, Default={StaticResource Black}}"/>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>

                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>

</ContentPage>

Here is my xaml.cs:
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using GppScanMaui.Clients;

namespace GppScanMaui.Menu;

[QueryProperty(nameof(MenuToLoad), "menuToLoad")]
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    public IReadOnlyList<ScanMenuItem>? MenuItems { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ScanMenuItem> MenuItemListData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ScanMenuItem>();

    public string MenuToLoad { private get; set; } = "Main";

    public MenuPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args) {
        if (Menus.MenuItems.TryGetValue(MenuToLoad, out var menuItems)) {
            MenuItems = menuItems.SubMenuItems;
            Title = menuItems.Text;
        }
        else {
            MenuItems = new List<ScanMenuItem>();
        }

        var allowedMenuItems = MenuItems.Where(item =>
            // There are no restrictions if there are no allowed groups
            item.AllowedGroups.Count == 0
            // If the user is an admin, they can see everything
            || (User.CurrentUser!.Groups?.Any(g => g == "Admin") ?? false)
            // If the user is in any of the allowed groups, at the specified location, they can see the item
            || item.AllowedGroups.Any(g => (User.CurrentUser!.Groups?.Contains(g.Group) ?? false) && (!g.Location.HasValue || g.Location == User.CurrentUser.Site)));

        MenuItemListData.Clear();
        foreach (var item in allowedMenuItems) {
            MenuItemListData.Add(item);
        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
    }

    private static void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.CurrentSelection.Count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        var itemName = ((ScanMenuItem)e.CurrentSelection[0]).Name;
        var path = $"""{itemName}?menuToLoad={itemName}""";
        Shell.Current.GoToAsync(path);
        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
}

And here is my ScanMenuItem.cs:
namespace GppScanMaui.Menu {
    public class ScanMenuItem {

        public ScanMenuItem(int position, string name, string text, string description, IReadOnlyList<ScanMenuItem>? subMenuItems = null, IReadOnlyList<GroupLocation>? allowedGroups = null) {
            Position = position;
            Name = name;
            Text = text;
            Description = description;
            SubMenuItems = subMenuItems ?? [];
            AllowedGroups = allowedGroups ?? [];
        }

        public int Position { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public string Text { get; }
        public string Description { get; }

        public IReadOnlyList<ScanMenuItem> SubMenuItems { get; init; } = [];

        public string DisplayName {
            get { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Position, Text); }
        }

        public IReadOnlyList<GroupLocation> AllowedGroups { get; init; } = [];
    }
}


Why not put Button in your DataTemplate?

Because a button can't hold any content (that I can tell) and there are a few pieces of data we want to display with styling.

Put the Button in a Grid. If need be, make the Button transparent (e.g. Opacity="0"), so you can put other things in the Grid that give the visual appearance, but, all the accessibility (including keyboard shortcuts) and the eventing (IsFocused, Clicked, etc) can be taken care of by the Button. e.g. <Grid><VerticalStackLayout><Label/><Label/></VerticalStackLayout><Button Opacity="0"/></Grid>

Or you could use this https://blog.stackademic.com/adding-native-click-effects-in-net-maui-dd3159a4b709

@FreakyAli that library doesn't support Border controls. I'm not determined to use one, I'm open to doing other things, but I'm not sure what to use in this case.

@StephenQuan my goal is to give the object the "pressed" look, so when tapped it changes the background color, to emulate a button.

@Lance I created that library all you have to do is add another Layout on top of border and then use it on that... That's exactly why I gave you the medium blog and not the github

@FreakyAli oh I see. Thanks. I think we might pull that library in, but in this case I realized we were already using a components library that I could use for this problem. Thanks for you input.

Good that you found what you needed :)

@Lance I've posted an answer explaining how to transfer PointerOver, Pressed visual states from a Button to your Border control.

I do something similar.  I have contentViews that define what my 'buttons' look like - tiles, rounds, single full width, and more.  After retrieving the menu items I create a grid with the number of columns I might need, then loop through the grid adding rows as needed.  Use ColumnSpan for items that should take up more than one column.
Hover state doesn't translate well to mobile because there isn't a mouse moving around the view.  You could change colors/shading when the item is tapped to give it a depressed look, but I have not found that useful, just changing the content of the view when the item is tapped seems sufficient.

I can't figure out how to determine when the item is tapped because the border object doesn't seem to have a "Pressed" state that I can key off of.

use a TapGestureRecognizer

I found this morning that Telerik UI for .NET MAUI has a TemplatedButton that can handle content, so I switched to using that. I appreciate all the input.

I wanted to expand upon the Grid Button solution:
<Grid>
    <!-- Custom appearance of Button here -->
    <!-- ... ->

    <!-- Actual Button here, but hidden -->
   <Button x:Name="btn" Opacity="0" />
</Grid>

By doing this, we can create custom appearance for our Button, but, still get behaviors of a Button, e.g. keyboard tab to focus, click, press, hover, etc.
Here's an example of transferring the VisualStates Normal, Pressed, PointerOver from the Button and applying it to the Border.Stroke color.
<Grid WidthRequest="300">
    <Border
        Margin="50,10"
        Padding="0,10"
        Stroke="{Binding BorderColor, Source={Reference btn}}"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10"
        StrokeThickness="4">
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Text" />
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Description" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Border>

    <Button x:Name="btn" Opacity="0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Lime" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Red" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Orange" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Button>
</Grid>


